# Shrink QVector to last 10 elements & rearrange one item

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I'm trying to find the most "efficient" way or, at least fast enough for 10k items vector to shrink it to last 10 items and move last selected item to the end of it.

I initially though of using this method for shrinking :

```
QVector<QModelIndex> newVec(listPrimary.end() - 10, listPrimary.end());
```

But that does not work, and I'm not sure how to use the Qt interators / std to get it to work...

And then once that's done do this test

```
if(newVec.contains(lastItem))
{
    newVec.insert(newVec[vewVec.indexOf(newVec)],newVec.size());
}
else{
    newVec.push_back(lastItem);
}
```

Comment: You might be able to do `auto newVec = listPrimary.mid(listPrimary.size() - 10)`

Answer (score 1):

QVector Class has a [method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#mid) that does what you want:

> **QVector QVector::mid(int pos, int length = ...) const**
>   Returns a sub-vector which contains elements from this vector, starting at position `pos`. If `length` is -1 (the default), all elements after `pos` are included; otherwise `length` elements (or all remaining elements if there are less than `length` elements) are included.

So as suggested in the comments, you can do something like this:

```
auto newVec = listPrimary.mid(listPrimary.size() - 10);
```

You do not have to pass `length` because its default value ensures that all elements after `pos` are included.